# Equation of smallest enclosing circle of three points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, computational-geometry

For any fixed three points or a triangle, the [smallest enclosing circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) is either their circumcircle or a circle centering at the midpoint of the largest side of the triangle.

Is there any way to write the equation of the smallest enclosing circle algebraically?

Comment: You've linked the wikipedia entry; do you have any insight of your own?  Edit it into your post.

Comment: i know the equation would depend on the nature of the triangle. in some case, it would be the equation of the circumcircle. but having hard time to figure out the complete equation. for a set of more than three points, it is impossible to express the equation of smallest enclosing circle algebraically.

Comment: A case distinction by whether one of the angles exceeds $90^\circ$ should allow you to succeed

Comment: You say _complete equation_.  What do you currently have?

Comment: i can write the euqation based on the triangle. i will have two equations. i am looking for one equation where i don't have to depend on the type of triangle.

Comment: You must consider three points $(x_1, y,_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ and (x_3, y_3). This will give you a general formula  thorough a messy and long algorithm.

Comment: What kind of functions you assume "algebraic"? Is $f(x)=|x|$ such a function?

Comment: yes. say, i want to express the radius of smallest enclosing circle. f(X) is the function that takes three points as domain and returns the radius of the smallest enclosing circle.

Comment: If the three points aren’t colinear, then the second possibility you describe is simply the circumcircle of a right triangle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle for various formulas pertaining to the circumcircle.

Comment: I understand what you want. My question was only about the allowed functions. For example The function $|x|$ is not differentiable, and $\theta(x)$ is not even continuous. Another example is the function $ \max(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. In other words: what functions are not allowed?